# How to create a fixed header and footer with dynamic content?

Tags: html, css, height

I have to make a layout with a `.header` and `.content` like with fixed height (for example 100px) and 100% width.

Then, I have to put a content with dynamical height that cover the void space.

```html
<!-- [...] -->
<style type="text/css">
  body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
  }
  
  .wrapper {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
  }
  
  .header {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0F0;
  }
  
  .footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #0F0;
  }
  
  .content {
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    background: #F00;
    padding: 100px 0;
    margin: -100px 0;
  }
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

This layout HAD to permit me to put a header and footer with fixed height, and a content with images that scale dimensions (inside a `div.content`).

Comment: Hi Lorenzo, what is the problem you are having? Could you try to explain a little more.

Comment: So you want the `.content` to fill the space between `.header` and `.footer`?

Comment: You want a HTML page with a scroll-fixed header and footer and scroll-able content?

Comment: yes, i'm unable to came out with a solution... friend tolds me that there is a javascript way... but i didn't find it..

Comment: @silvinci the web-site will be horizontal scrolling... so i need a layout that covers 100% in height... so that isn't scrollable in height but only in width

Comment: Where do you want the scrollbar to appear? In the `.content` or in the `html`?

Comment: i don't want the scrollbar appear. I'll do by javascript ( or just with 2 arrows... )

Comment: Do you want the whole page designed in that style or only a showcase/wrapper?

Comment: well... the site will be in wordpress, but the horizontal layout will be just in the homepage... so it's just a single page showcase

Answer (score 4):

First of all: If you have a unique element, like a page header/footer, please use an `id` and not a `class`. A `class` is used for elements that appear frequently or have something in common that makes it semantically correct to group them, like description texts.

Now your problem. We have to give the `html` and `body` a total height of 100% so they won't resize and we can be sure that we will use the whole page.

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

You then used a wrapper, but we can omit that. `<body>` is already a wrapper. The `header` and `footer` explain their self.

```
#header {
    height: 100px;

    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    background: #0F0;
}
#footer {
    height: 100px;

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    background: #0F0;
}
```

The `content` is a bit tricky. It needs to be expanded to `100% - 100px at the top - 100px at the bottom`. Impossible? No.

```
#content {
    position: absolute;

    top: 100px;
    bottom: 100px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;

    overflow: hidden; /* No scrollbars | Make this 'auto' if you want them */

    background: #F00;
}
```

Finished. You can have a look at it on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UdMAF/4/).

Comment: Another option is to use width: 100% instead of right and left. You save one line.

Comment: @Nashenas Correct. Though I prefer to stick to positioning, once I started using it. Old habits die hard, I guess. :D